# How rto add an object with ServiceStack Redis

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

I am implementing ServiceStack Redis(version 4) in my c# application for the first time an having issues storing entities.

I first implemented  the “add” method in the below interface:

```
public interface ICacheClient : IDisposable
    bool Add<T>(string key, T value, DateTime expiresAt);

public void Add<TValue>(string key, TValue value)where TValue : class, new()
{
   _redisClient.Add(_cachePrefix + key, value);
}
```

This didn’t seem to store the object which came back null upon retrieval:

```
_redisClient.GetById<TValue>(91876);
```

So I implemented the “store” method instead(storing the same entity—(value and video are the same object)) and stored the same entity as above:

```
IEntityStore
   T Store<T>(T entity);
```

redisClient.Store(video);

And retrieved it with:

`_redisClient.GetById<TValue>(91876)`;

Now Im able to retrieve the entity.

My question is why would the store method as described work and not the add method?

Can I store objects  with the add method?

Answer (score 0):

The `Add` method on `ICacheClient` requires you to supply the full key string to the cached entity, whereas the `GetById` method only requires the Id.

All methods on [ICacheClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Caching/ICacheClient.cs) always require the full cache key to retrieve cached data. Where the high-level API's on [IRedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs) or [IRedisTypedClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisTypedClient.cs) are able to operate on just the Entity and Id.